# Help identifying a bug which looks like a housefly and mosquito hybrid

Tags: species-identification, entomology, hybridization

I'm from Kochi, India (*southern part of India*). I found this bug inside my house , it was about a centimeter long . But how can such an hybrid be possible. (*It was raining before I found it*).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoUEm.jpg): [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlyio.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Do you have some reason to assume this is a hybrid? If not, that is an extremely naïve assumption to make and I encourage you to remove it from your question. Please also [edit] additional information such as local ecological factors including the dominant types of plants and if possible clear close-up pictures from multiple angles. This may enable someone to narrow down the identification of this insect.  ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score -1):

This is a long-legged fly (Condylostylus spp).  Unfortunately your image is not sharp enough to give a specific species.  See this post of another Indian fly that is virtually identical to yours:
https://www.jungledragon.com/image/13762/long-legged_fly_-_condylostylus_spp.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, Your post does not provide enough evidence /support for you to definitively claim the genus of the OP's specimen. Please consider explaining *why* you think this is the correct genus.

Comment: The OP and many other visitors will likely see your post and consider it fact. This is insincere given that it appears (based on what evidence you provide here) that you simply did a Google image search. The picture you link to is from a photography website with no evidence of taxonomic expertise. (It seems to just be amateur photographers tagging their own photos). Much more convincing and reputable sources exist and should be used as support if you truly feel confident in your answer. Again, please consider updating to strengthen your answer. Thank you